# How do i fix the array out of bounds exception?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying extract the coefficients and exponents from a string array. for example: "x^2 + 2x + 1" or "x^5" or "x^2 -x + 1". The code I wrote in this Polynomial constructor works for most cases but when the length of the string is one I am getting a index out of bounds error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1". I am not sure how to fix this. Can anyone help me with this code?

I've tried to break the while loop if the length of the array is 1.

```
public class Polynomial extends PolynomialInterface {
    public Polynomial(String s) {
        // complete this code
        Term newTerm;
        DList<Term> dList = new DList<Term>();

        int exp = 0;
        double coef = 0;

        s = s.replaceAll(" ", "");



        String[] array = s.split("\\+|(?=-)");


       for(String i : array){
            System.out.println("split: " + i);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {

                while (array[i].contains("x")) {

                    exp = 0;

                    if ((array[i].substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("x"))) {
                        coef = 1;
                    }


                    if (array[i].substring(0, 1).equals("-") && array[i].substring(1, 2).equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
                        coef = -1;
                        exp = 1;
                    }


                    if (array[i].contains("^")) {

                        int index = array[i].indexOf("^");
                        String myString = "";

                        if (index != -1) {
                            myString = array[i].substring(index + 1, index + 2);
                            if (!myString.isEmpty()) {
                                exp = Integer.parseInt(myString);
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    if (!array[i].contains("^")) {
                        exp = 1;
                    }




                    int end = array[i].indexOf("x");

                    String subString = "";

                    if (end != -1) {
                        subString = array[i].substring(0, end);
                        if (!subString.isEmpty() && !subString.contains("-")) {
                            coef = Double.parseDouble(subString);
                        } else if (!subString.isEmpty() && !subString.equals("-")) {
                            coef = Double.parseDouble(subString);

                        }
                    }


                    newTerm = new Term(coef, exp);
                    dList.addLast(newTerm);

                    if(array.length==1){
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;

                }

                while (array[i].matches("([-]\\d*|\\d*)") && (i < array.length)) {


                    coef = Double.parseDouble(array[i]);
                    exp = 0;

                    newTerm = new Term(coef, exp);
                    dList.addLast(newTerm);


                    break;

                }
            }








        //super.data = dList;



        }
```

When I debugged I got the right coefficients and exponents then it iterates and I get a index out of bounds error

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++)` ... you  do understand that Java has zero-based indexing, right? That means that the last element is at `array.length - 1` not at `array.length`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++)
```

Your for loop goes to array.length, what causes the null pointer exception.
Remember in java arrays start at 0 and end at array.length-1, so your contition should be 
i < array.length

Comment: Please do not answer if the indicated duplicate already has the same answer.